# In Oracle PL/SQL , what is the maximum length of a Trigger name?

Tags: plsql, triggers

I was wondering about the maximum length for an Oracle Trigger name.

I know that for Sproc's it is 30 . Is it same for trigger?

Thanks !

Comment: It's an identifier like any other identifier, so it's also limited to 30 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As user a_horse_with_no_name  says above in comments, because a trigger name is also an identifier ,  then the rule applies - [the maximum is 30 characters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS002)